# Should I make my SQL query asynchronous in the following case instance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, asynchronous

To summarize my issue: I have to make 3 separate calls to 3 different endpoints. I have to do this programatically through a large list of records. Two of the calls are made using asynchronous HTTP requests to two different in which I use aysnc await. The third call I have to make is a query to a MS SQL database that does not have an API wrapper. The two calls to the APIs take ~22 seconds each and the query to the database takes ~2 seconds. Individually this is fine, however when I make the MS SQL query part of the method chain, the entire thing becomes synchronous. And where I would have originally saved the user a lot of time doing simultaneous queries to the two APIs, my app will wait for these queries to be completed before attempting the next call to the database.

I have previously been told that database queries are transactional and cannot be made asynchronous. I am wondering if this is true and I can actually make a truly asynchronous call to the database.

My other option is to pre-populate a `List<T>` of objects that I can create from the series of SQL queries to the database when the job is executed. However my worry is the potential number of objects stored in this List, whether it will be in danger of overloading memory for certain jobs that require hundreds of thousands of records to be processed, or possibly the speed of searching through the objects to pull the correct values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> when I make the MS SQL query part of the method chain, the entire thing becomes synchronous.

That is an incorrect implementation. You can most certainly mix synchronous and asynchronous calls inside a single function.

Let's say you have these three methods:

```
async Task<Result1> FirstQueryAsync() {
    ...
}
async Task<Result2> SecondQueryAsync() {
    ...
}
Result3 QueryDb() {
}
```

You can write this:

```
async Task<OverallResult> QueryThreeSources() {
    // Fire off async queries
    var firstTask = FirstQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    var secondTask = SecondQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // Do synchronous query
    var third = QueryDb();
    // Await the results of the other two
    var first = await firstTask;
    var second = await secondTask;
    return Combine(first, second, third);
}
```

> I have previously been told that database queries are transactional and cannot be made asynchronous.

This is incorrect. Transactional nature of querying manifests itself on the RDBMS side, inside RDBMS. This is completely independent from the decision of your program to receive its data synchronously or asynchronously. .NET provides asynchronous APIs for accessing SQL Server, so you can definitely rewrite your DB code using asynchronous style.

> My other option is to pre-populate a `List<T>` of objects that I can create from the series of SQL queries to the database when the job is executed.

List option would be good only if you query the same data multiple times. If all your queries tend to bring different subsets of the data, which are small in comparison to the overall data stored in the table that you query, caching the data in `List<T>`s is usually counterproductive.

Comment: In my implementation should I open my SQL connection and pass the connection into the the method that queries my three sources, or should I open a new connection and then close it at the end of each new call of this method?